# Why use "Kies" and not "Kiua"?

Tags: word-difference, possessive

Esperanto seems to have a unique word for *whose* -- *kies*.

I don't see the need.

Esperanto already has the possessive *-a* ending. I don't see why we can't apply *kiua* as show below:

1. A simple question and answer. *Kio* turns into *boto*.

   - *Kio estas tio?* - What is that?
   - *Tio estas boto!* - That is a boot!
2. If we make it an accusative, the *-n* remains as *Kion* turns into *boton*.

   - *Kion manĝas ĝi?* - What is it eating?
   - *Ĝi manĝas boton!* - It is eating a boot!
3. Same as 1. but asking *Kiu?* instead of *Kio?*.

   - *Kiu estas ĝi?* - Who is it?
   - *Ĝi estas li.* - It is him.
4. Similar to 2., but possessive instead of accusative.

   - ***Kies estas ĝi?*** - Whose is it? <-- Whyyyy?
   - ***Kiua estas ĝi?*** - Whose is it? <-- This is so much more intuitive!
   - *Ĝi estas lia.* - It is his.

I need answers! Someone please help restore my faith in constructed language!

Note: If I made any mistakes in my translations, please comment.

Comment: Since the correlatives include _-es_ words to show possession, this has inspired some (very few) to use _-es_ as genitive marker, especially with names. So instead of writing _La domo de Adamo estas bela_ they write _Adames domo estas bela_. Let me stress that this kind of use is highly experimental, neither widely known nor accepted. No, I do not know how to mark accusative in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### tl;dr:

That wouldn't work without a major (probably *kontraŭfundamenta*) reform to Esperanto, as *-a* has a possessive meaning *only when* attached to a personal pronoun (*mi*, *vi*, *li*, *ŝi*, *ĝi*, *si*, *ni* or *ili*). *kiu* however isn't a personal pronoun, but one of the [tabelvortoj](https://lernu.net/gramatiko/tabelvortoj) ("table words", a system of questions words, correlatives, etc.)

### Why is it *kies* rather than *kiua*?

Because the [Fundamento de Esperanto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamento_de_Esperanto) kinda says so [in its exercices](https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/ekzercaro.html#ekzerco30) and [in its dictionary](https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/universala_vortaro.html#av-2057). (The very minimal [grammar part](https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko.html) of the fundamento (a.k.a. the (in)famous "16 rules" of Esperanto) doesn't seem to mention it.)

And because contemporary Esperanto in actual everyday use doesn't deviate from (nor amends to) the Fundamento in that regard.

### Why does the Fundamento say so?

Because L.L. Zamenhof wrote it that way.

### Why did Zamenhof write the Fundamento that way?

We can't ask him anymore, so we have to rely on written (or otherwise preserved) sources from back then—early drafts of what later became Esperanto, letters, books, etc.—and on similarities to pre-existing languages that Zamenhof knew. Some of the guesswork that can be extracted from those sources and similarities has been condensed into entries of etymological dictionaries, but few of those cover pronouns and correlatives in-depth.

*Etimologia Vortaro de Esperanto* by Ebbe Vilborg is a notable exception, and *Konciza Etimologia Vortaro* by André Cherpillod at least has a short (and probably well-researched) entry on it:

#### André Cherpillod about the "…es" part of possessive tabelvortoj

> **-es** F (posedaj pronomoj)**.** G **des** «ties», **wes** «kies», F **à qui est-ce?** *akies* «kies estas?».

— Konciza Etimologia Vortaro

##### explanation

The first "F" means that the morpheme is *Fundamenta* (already defined by the Fundamento, not by official amendments or even only (yet) unofficial additions to Esperanto by its users). "G" means *la germana* (the German language) and "F" *la franca* (the French language). "akies" is a transcription using Esperanto letters of how the French expression "à qui est-ce?" is (approximately) pronounced, to illustrate how it could also be the (or a) source or inspiration of the "…es" ending for possessives.

#### Ebbe Vilborg on "kies" and other "…es"-table-words

##### kies

> **KIES** (f; Un): Vd. la sekcion pri korelativaj vortoj. ¶ 1894 *de kvu* ("de kiu"). ¶ Io *di qua*, Ie *de qui*, *de quel*, Ia *cuje* (< L *cius*, H *cuyo*).
> HE originformo **kŭeso*; kp ank. G *wes(sen)*.

##### ties

> **TIES** (f', 7; PR): Vd. la sekcion pri korelativaj vortoj. ¶ Mankas en la aliaj L.I. (Io *di ita*, Ia *de ti*, Ia *de iste/ille*).

##### ies

> **IES** (f; Un): Vd. la sekcion pri korelativaj vortoj. ¶ 1894 *de alikvu* ¶ Io *di ulu*, *di ula*, Ie *de alqui*, Ia *de alicun*.

##### ĉies

> **ĈIES** (f', 7; PR): Vd. la sekcion pri korelativaj vortoj. ¶ Io *di omnu*, *di omni*, Ie *de chascun*, *de omnes*, Ia *de omne(s)*.

##### nenies

> **NENIES** (f; Un): Vd. la sekcion pri korelativaj vortoj. ¶ 1894 *de nemo* ('de neniu'). ¶ Io *di nulu*, Ie *de nequi*, Ia *de necuno [nemo]*.

— Etimologia Vortaro de Esperanto

Whoa, that's a lot of abbreviations. What do they mean?

##### general abbreviations

Vd.

vidu

L.I.

lingvoj internaciaj

##### source abbreviations

f

Fundamenta radiko

f'

radiko trovebla en la Fundamento ekster Universala Vortaro

Un

Unua Libro (1887)

PR

Poŝa Lernolibro por Rusoj (1890)

7

radiko oficialigita en la sepa Oficiala Aldono

##### language abbreviations

1894

Zamenhof's (proposed) Esperanto variant / reform from that year

Ia

Interlingua, another planned auxiliary language

Ie

Interlingue (a.k.a. Occidental), another planned auxiliary language

Io

Ido, a planned auxiliary language derived from Esperanto

L

la latina (Latin)

H

la hispana (Spanish)

HE

hindeŭropa pralingvo ([Proto-Indo-European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language))

G

la germana (German)

So it seems that the "…es" of the possessive tabelvortoj may come from German and/or French and can (via Latin) be traced even back to common Indo-European roots.

### Why did Zamenhof include that "…es", though? Isn't it unnecessary?

It's indeed not strictly necessary, as the Zamenhof's own aforementioned reform ideas from 1894 show, where expressions with the possesive-indicating preposition "de" + another tabelvorto seem to be used. That's something that's (with the *Fundamenta* variant of those other tabelvortoj) would probably be permissible in today's Esperanto, too, but not usually considered good style. (It *is* being used in certain sentence constructions and/or with specific connotations.)

- *de kiu* ≅ *kies*
- *de tiu* ≅ *ties*
- *de iu* ≅ *ies*
- *de ĉiu* ≅ *ĉies*
- *de neniu* ≅ *nenies*

A possible explanation of why Zamenhof included it (or for that matter, a distinct type of table words for possessives at all), anyway, might well be that he consciously or unconsciously mirrored structures in other languages he knew (such as German).

### But why not "…u" + "-a"?

Whether he didn't even consider that or whether he did and decided against it, I do not know. But let's look at it from a contemporary perspective.

Would that (*kiua* etc.) be allowable in today's Esperanto? Probably not. Here's why:

#### grammatical considerations

One has to be aware, that there are 3 to 4 distinct word-systems in Esperanto.

- The well-known word-building system with roots (e.g. *dom·*), affixes (e.g. *mal-* & *-et·*) and word-type indicating endings (e.g. -o)
- The personal pronouns *mi*, *vi*, *li*, *ŝi*, *ĝi*, *si*, *ni* and *ili* (and unofficial ones like *ri*)
- (particles like prepositions etc.)
- The correlatives (tabelvortoj)

One can to some extent mix-and-match morphemes from these different systems, but not as freely as within each system.

*-a* has a possessive meaning *only when* attached to personal pronouns. In the general word-building system, *-a* has a rather different meaning: It's the word-type indicating ending for adjectives. (Those are somewhat related: A possessive personal pronoun grammatically acts kinda like an adjective. But they aren't the same, as not all adjectives have possessive meaning.)

The *-j* and *-n* one can attach to *some* tabelvortoj can either be considered tabelvortoj-rows of their own or as modifying endings from the general word-building system, but not really as part of the personal pronoun system. Note that of them, only *-n* can be attached also to personal pronouns (to indicate accusative), but not *-j*. (Plural is instead indicated by different personal pronouns *ni* and *ili* or even by the same (*vi*).)

Similarly, one can't attach the personal pronoun ending *-a* to tabelvortoj.

##### Danger of misunderstandings

And if one would do so anyway, it would probably be mistaken for the general word-building system *-a* that, as mentioned above, carries a different meaning. (And attaching *that* to (some) tabelvortoj *is already* idiomatic, namely to those ending in *…om*: Typically to ask about the time: "La **kioma** [horo] estas?")

#### phonological considerations

How would the result be pronounced?

- *kies* ≅ **kiua* (3 syllables: *ki-u-a*)
- *ties* ≅ **tiua* (3 syllables: *ti-u-a*)
- *ies* ≅ **iua* (3 syllables: *i-u-a*)
- *ĉies* ≅ **ĉiua* (3 syllables: *ĉi-u-a*)
- *nenies* ≅ **neniua* (4 syllables: *ne-ni-u-a*)

As each vowel in Esperanto denotes a syllable of its own *iua* would be a 3-letter word with 3 syllables, consisting only of vowels. While it's physically possible to pronounce this (and for many speakers probably not even very difficult), such a vowel cluster is rather unusual in Esperanto and would probably sound un-Esperanto-like to many Esperantists. Usual Esperanto syllables (Note that morpheme boundaries (i.e., boundaries of the word-building parts) and syllable boundaries often don't coincide in Esperanto.) include (besides the vowel) at least one consonant or pseudo-consonant (*j* or *ŭ*).

Comment: TODO: Read the mentioned _sekcion pri korelativaj vortoj_ in _Etimologia Vortaro de Esperanto_ and quote / cite the relevant parts. (That'll have to wait until tomorrow or another day, though.)

Comment: Wow, great answer! Very thorough. Perhaps you can add a TL;DR for busy people?

Comment: Gladly, but what would the TL;DR of this answer be, @DabaMcD? I'm not quite sure what the most central points are that should be included in such a summary. Which do you consider TL;DR-worthy? (One of the reasons the answer is as long as it is, was, that I wasn't sure whether your question is about etymology/language history, about possibility of changing Esperanto now/using it differently or about how to design a hypothetical "better" planned language.)

Comment: Ah, good point. I was asking a very broad question as a beginner, so for me the highlight is "-a has a possessive meaning only when attached to personal pronouns". For me personally, the tabelvortoj mention was super helpful because I've been learning through Duolingo and they don't cite resources, but I understand if you don't include that in the TL;DR

Comment: A better beginner's course in my mind is the one in [Lernu](https://lernu.net/kurso/nakamura), because that explains grammar – and has a story. Note that the browser version of Duolingo at least used to have some grammar while the mobile application version has never had.

Answer (score 3):

> Esperanto already has the possessive -a ending.

`-a` [havas plurajn signifojn](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/a-vortoj/bazaj_reguloj.html), ne nur aparteno. Tial oni bezonas alian tabelvorton por tio.

> I don't see why we can't apply kiua as show below:

Tabelvortoj havas siajn proprajn regulojn, pri vortfarado. Ili havas nur du partojn. Vi povas poste kunmeti, aldoni prefiksojn kaj sufiksojn, diri aferojn kiel ekzemple "mi sen/kial/e malgajiĝis". Sed la tabelvorto nur havas du partojn, ĉi okaze `ki` + `al`.

Cetere notu ke ili estas *vortoj*, do memstaraj, ne disigeblaj, vi ne povas enmeti ion inter tiujn du elementojn.

[Jen la tuta tabelo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/tabelvortoj/bazaj_reguloj.html#j-u3j).

Ĉu oni estus povinta tion fari alimaniere? Jes, tutcerte (la ida lingvo ekzemple ne havas tabelvortoj faritaj tiel regule). Tabelvortoj estas kerna parto de la lingvo, kaj ili estas plene antaŭdifinitaj (kvankam kelkaj parolantoj klopodas [tabelvortigi  `ali-`](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/tabelvortoj/ali-vortoj.html)).

Tia estas la lingvo nun. Permesi al tabelvortoj havi plurajn elementojn, kiel en via `kiua` ŝanĝegus la lingvon. Antaŭ ol proponi ion tian vi devus tamen fari novan tabelon kiel la supre menciitan kaj klarigi la signifon de ĉiu kunmetaĵo kun du elementoj, ekzemple `kiau` (kun la `a` kaj `u` inverse).